# how to call a function in another function?

Tags: python

I want to call a function in another function. Is it how it`s done?

```
#=========#=========#=========#=========#
def text_file():
    filename = 'text.txt'
    return filename

#=========#=========#=========#=========#
def show_log():  ##  Main log function, 
    #filename = 'text.txt'
    if not os.path.exists(text_file()): # if text.txt does not exists than create one
        file(text_file(), 'w').close()

    if os.path.getsize(text_file()) > 0: # if text.txt is not empty show the menu
        log_menu()
    else: # if text.txt is empty
        print
        print "  You have not draw anything yet!"
        print
        raw_input('  Press Enter to continue ')
    return
```

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. Can you be more precise?

Comment: that works, but it might be more efficient to just call it once at the beginning of show_log(), and assign it to a local variable.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: If you test before asking "Is it how it`s done?", you'll notice that you already have found out how it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, i cleaned up the code a little. Hope it makes sense.

```
def text_file():
    return 'text.txt'

def show_log():  ##  Main log function, 
    filename = text_file()
    if os.path.exists(filename) and os.path.getsize(filename): # if text.txt is not empty show the menu
        log_menu()
    else: # no textfile there or its empty
        print
        print "  You have not draw anything yet!"
        print
        raw_input('  Press Enter to continue ')
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

Same way as anywhere else.

```
filename = text_file()
```